# creating a table in database with postgresql . (springBoot)

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot

Error executing DDL

```
create table professeurs (
    id int8 generated by default as identity,
    montant int4,
    pourcentage int4,
    prenom varchar(255),
    adresse varchar(255),
    categorie varchar(255),
    datenaissance varchar(255),
    diplome varchar(255),
    nom varchar(255),
    prix d 'heure int4, 
    telephone int4, 
    primary key (id)
)
```

via JDBC Statement?

Comment: whats the error message ?

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

I think its because of the column name "prix d 'heure" , you can scape single quote by using double quotes:

```
create table professeurs (
    id int8 generated by default as identity,
    montant int4,
    pourcentage int4,
    prenom varchar(255),
    adresse varchar(255),
    categorie varchar(255),
    datenaissance varchar(255),
    diplome varchar(255),
    nom varchar(255),
    "prix d 'heure" int4, 
    telephone int4, 
    primary key (id)
)
```

Comment: Correct. But it is clearly better to avoid non-standard column names at all.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe also correct ;)

Comment: cava ca marche , j'ai changé prix d'heure par prix_dheure . merci

Comment: Parfait ! Please accept / upvote the answer if it helped